# Chordal Graphs and Minimal Separators. Confusion over Proof.

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I am studying some Graph Theory and am confused by the proof of the following statement:

> A connected graph $G$, which is not complete, is chordal (has no chordless cycles of length $\geq{4}$) if and only if each of its minimal (with respect to set inclusion) separators is a clique.

Now by my understanding a separator of $G$ is a set $X$ of vertices of G that separates $G$, that is $G-X$ is disconnected. A $\textit{minimal}$ separator of $G$ is a such a set that does not contain another separator as a proper subset.

Now the bit of the proof that adresses the reverse implication (if each minimal separator is a clique then $G$ is chordal), reads:

> Suppose now that every minimal separator in $G$ is a clique. Assume $G$ has a chordless cycle $(v_{1},...,v_{k})$ with k $\geq{4}$. Let X be a minimal set separating $v_{1}$ from $v_{3}$. Obviously, $X$ must contain $v_{2}$ and at least one vertex from $v_{4},...,v_{k}$ since otherwise $G-X$ contains a path connecting $v_{1}$ to $v_{3}$. By our assumption, $X$ is a clique. On the other hand $v_{2}$ has no neighbours among $v_{4},...v_{k}$. This contradiction shows that $G$ has no chordless cycles of length $4$ or more i.e. $G$ is chordal.

Unless I am missing something, we have not assumed that $X$ is a clique. We have assumed that all minimal separators of $G$ are cliques. $X$ is a set that separates $v_{1}$ from $v_{3}$, without any proper subset of $X$ doing the same. That does not mean that a proper subset of $X$ does not separate another pair of vertices of $G$ right? In other words, $X$ being a minimal $(v_{1},v_{3})-separator$ does not imply that $X$ is a minimal separator of $G$.

Am I missing something here?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this result to be true you need the following definition of minimal separator (taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_separator)):

> Let $S$ be an $(a,b)$-separator, that is, a vertex subset that separates two nonadjacent vertices $a$ and $b$. Then S is a minimal $(a,b)$-separator if no proper subset of $S$ separates $a$ and $b$. More generally, $S$ is called a minimal separator if it is a minimal separator for some pair $(a,b)$ of nonadjacent vertices.

With this definition, the proof is fine - a minimal $(v_1,v_3)$-separator is a minimal separator.

With the definition you might intuitively expect - a set which separates the graph but has no proper subset which does - the result would not be true, as shown by the following graph. The only minimal sets which separate are the singleton sets of red vertices, all of which are trivial cliques.

[image: non-chordal graph]

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful.